# How to dispose the progress bar?

Tags: java, swt

I newer for SWT.

This is the code for displaying progress bar. While clicking 'Cancel' button in my application,progress bar should run. It is working.. After the work also it is till displaying only.. how to kill this after my work??

```
                    public static void Pv7(Button ok, Shell shell2) 
                    {
                        shell=shell2;

                        final ProgressBar pb3 = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.SMOOTH);

                        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout()); 
                        shell.setSize(1500, 1000);

                        pb3.setSelection(500);
                        pb3.setBounds(100, 40, 200, 20);

                        Label label3 = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
                        //label2.setText("Success");
                        label3.setAlignment(SWT.LEFT);
                        label3.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 20);
                    }
                        __________________

                My code is displaying the progress after the process also. How to dispose the progress bar the after the another shell window opened??

            This is my main program:

    import org.eclipse.swt.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

    public class Practice1 
    {
        static Text text = null;
        final static Shell shell = null;

        public static void main (String [] args) 
        {
            final Display display =new Display();
            final Shell shell=new Shell(display);

            RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();

            shell.setLayout(rowLayout);
                        shell.setLocation(-1,-7);
            shell.setBounds(0, 0, 1050, 720);

            Label label = new Label (shell, SWT.NONE);
            label.setText ("Enter the text:");

            text = new Text (shell, SWT.BORDER);

            final Button ok = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
            ok.setText ("OK");
            ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
            {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
                {

                    PV6.Pv6(ok,shell);
                }
            });

            Button cancel = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
            cancel.setText ("Cancel");
            cancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
            {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Cancel");
                    System.out.println("User cancelled dialog");

                    shell.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() 
            {
                    public void handleEvent(Event event) 
                {
                    int style = SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;
                    MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, style);
                    messageBox.setText("Information");
                    messageBox.setMessage("Close the shell?");
                    event.doit = messageBox.open() == SWT.YES;
                }
                    });

            shell.setDefaultButton (cancel);

            /*print the ID in the console area**/

            ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println(text.getText());
                } 
            });


            //Creating another shell

            ok.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
            {

                @Override
                public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) 
                {
                                            System.out.println(text.getText()); 


                    final Shell dialog = new Shell (shell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog.setText("Dialog Shell");
                    dialog.setBounds(50,100, 10, 10);
                    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout ();
                    formLayout.marginWidth = 10;
                    formLayout.marginHeight = 10;

                    dialog.setLayout (formLayout);

                    Label label = new Label (dialog, SWT.NONE);
                    label.setText ("Type a Name:");
                    FormData data = new FormData ();
                    label.setLayoutData (data);

                    Button cancel = new Button (dialog, SWT.PUSH);
                    cancel.setText ("Cancel");

                    data = new FormData ();
                    data.width = 60;
                    data.right = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                    data.bottom = new FormAttachment (100, 0);

                    cancel.setLayoutData (data);
                    cancel.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) 
                        {

                            System.out.println("User cancelled dialog");
                            dialog.close ();
                        }
                    });

                    text = new Text (dialog, SWT.BORDER);
                    data = new FormData ();
                    data.width = 200;
                    data.left = new FormAttachment (label, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                    data.right = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                    data.top = new FormAttachment (label, 0, SWT.CENTER);
                    data.bottom = new FormAttachment (cancel, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                    text.setLayoutData (data);

                    final Button ok = new Button (dialog, SWT.PUSH);
                    ok.setText ("OK");
                    data = new FormData ();
                    data.width = 60;
                    data.right = new FormAttachment (cancel, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                    data.bottom = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                    ok.setLayoutData (data);

                    ok.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e)
                        {
                            System.out.println (" " + text.getText ());
                            PV6.Pv6(ok,shell);
                            //  dialog.close ();
                        }
                    });

                    //Creating another shell

                    ok.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) 
                        {
                            //PV6.Pv6(ok,shell);
                            System.out.println(text.getText()); 


                            final Shell dialog = new Shell (shell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                            dialog.setText("Dialog Shell");
                            FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout ();
                            formLayout.marginWidth = 50;
                            formLayout.marginHeight = 10;
                            formLayout.spacing = 100;

                            dialog.setLayout (formLayout);

                            Label label = new Label (dialog, SWT.NONE);
                            label.setText ("Type a Name:");
                            FormData data = new FormData ();
                            label.setLayoutData (data);

                            Button cancel = new Button (dialog, SWT.PUSH);
                            cancel.setText ("Cancel");

                            data = new FormData ();
                            data.width = 60;
                            data.right = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                            data.bottom = new FormAttachment (100, 0);

                            cancel.setLayoutData (data);
                            cancel.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e) 
                                {

                                    System.out.println("User cancelled dialog");
                                    dialog.close ();
                                }
                            });

                            text = new Text (dialog, SWT.BORDER);
                            data = new FormData ();
                            data.width = 200;
                            data.left = new FormAttachment (label, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                            data.right = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                            data.top = new FormAttachment (label, 0, SWT.CENTER);
                            data.bottom = new FormAttachment (cancel, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                            text.setLayoutData (data);

                            final Button ok = new Button (dialog, SWT.PUSH);
                            ok.setText ("OK");
                            data = new FormData ();
                            data.width = 60;
                            data.right = new FormAttachment (cancel, 0, SWT.DEFAULT);
                            data.bottom = new FormAttachment (100, 0);
                            ok.setLayoutData (data);

                            ok.addSelectionListener (new SelectionAdapter () 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e)
                                {
                                    System.out.println ("User typed: " + text.getText ());

                                    PV6.Pv6(ok,shell);
                                    //  dialog.close ();
                                }
                            });                         dialog.setDefaultButton (ok);
                            dialog.pack ();
                            dialog.open ();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.setDefaultButton (ok);
                    dialog.pack ();
                    dialog.open ();

                    // Move the dialog to the center of the top level shell. 
                    Rectangle shellBounds = shell.getBounds(); 
                    Point dialogSize = dialog.getSize(); 

                    //shell.setBounds(0, 0, 1050, 720);

                    dialog.setLocation( 
                            shellBounds.x + (shellBounds.width - dialogSize.x) / 2, 
                            shellBounds.y + (shellBounds.height -  dialogSize.y) / 2);
                }
            });
            shell.pack ();
            shell.open ();

            while (!shell.isDisposed ())
            {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
            }
            display.dispose ();
        }
    }            

                Any one help me for dispose the progress bar??
```

Comment: Where is the code of the "work" that is being done?

Comment: import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Practice1 
{
 static Text text = null;
 final static Shell shell = null;

 public static void main (String [] args) 
 {
  final Display display =new Display();
  final Shell shell=new Shell(display);
RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
shell.setLayout(rowLayout);
shell.setLocation(-1,-7);
  shell.setBounds(0, 0, 1050, 720);

Comment: Label label = new Label (shell, SWT.NONE);
  label.setText ("Enter the text:");
text = new Text (shell, SWT.BORDER);
final Button ok = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
  ok.setText ("OK");
  ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
  {
   @Override
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
   {

    PV6.Pv6(ok,shell);
   }
  });
shell.pack ();
  shell.open ();
while (!shell.isDisposed ())
  {
   if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
  }
  display.dispose ();
 }
}

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27458905/edit) your question and add the code there, it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: Code added in Question @ Baz

Comment: I don't see anything that does any work. All you do is add a `ProgressBar` to the `Shell` when the user presses a `Button`. When do you want to remove it again?

Comment: BTW: Please start using `Layout`s instead of positioning things absolutely. You'll get into trouble when people use a different resolution than you do otherwise. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) is a goog tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and then for this tutorial.. Sorry i missed the code yesterday.. now i modified the code.. Could you please check with this code ..

Comment: i have to dispose the progress bar, after the another shell window will dispaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't say that I fully understand your question. I don't know when exactly you want to dispose the `ProgressBar`, but I'll just explain how you can do it and then you decide when to call that method:

```
private static Shell shell;
private static ProgressBar bar;

public static void Pv7(Button ok, Shell shell2) 
{
    shell=shell2;

    if(bar != null && !bar.isDisposed())
        bar.dispose();

    bar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.SMOOTH);

    shell.setLayout(new RowLayout()); 
    shell.setSize(1500, 1000);

    pb3.setSelection(500);

    Label label3 = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
    label3.setAlignment(SWT.LEFT);
}

public static void disposeProgressBar()
{
    if(bar != null && !bar.idDisposed())
        bar.dispose();
}
```

Then just call `disposeProgressBar()` when you want the `ProgressBar` to be disposed.

Comment: Thank you Baz for your Answer. If the second window start to display then the progress bar should dispose.. I think am calling this method in wrong place? Where to call this method?

Comment: @AfshanAhamed Since I still don't understand what you're actually trying to do, I can't really help you. If you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (something I can just copy/paste and run) and also describe what the desired outcome is and why the current outcome isn't what you want, then I may be able to help you.

Comment: once the ok button clicked,another window start to display .. for that i have to show the progress bar.. The progress bar is displaying .. upto this no problem.. After i start working in second window, the progress bar should not be visible.. My code is not hiding the progress bar after the purpose of that. Here am unable to paste the image for my output.. Could you give your mail id please?

Comment: @AfshanAhamed No, sorry, I don't give away my email address. Please consider what I wrote in my previous comment, I won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: @ Baz.
The code should start with a blank canvas with just SAVE button on it.
When the SAVE button is clicked, a progress viewer should pop up and process till 10 seconds.
Then a popup stating SAVED SUCCESSFULLY should be displayed with OK and CLOSE button
It should come back to the first screen, with just the save button on it.
The placement of the progress viewer should be just below the save button
A parameter should be passed for the time the progress viewer is to be displayed, eg 10 for 10 seconds. If we want to change it to 15, there should be a change in the parameter value only

Comment: @AfshanAhamed Obviously, I can't. Please stop bombarding me with comments.